# How can I pass query string to HttpRequest.url_for() in actix-web?

Tags: rust, actix-web

[Documentation](https://docs.rs/actix-web/0.3.0/actix_web/struct.HttpRequest.html) about url_for.

Code:

```
fn index(req: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse {
    let url = req.url_for("foo", &["1", "2", "3"]); // <- generate url for "foo" resource
    HTTPOk.into()
}

fn main() {
    let app = Application::new()
        .resource("/test/{one}/{two}/{three}", |r| {
             r.name("foo");  // <- set resource name, then it could be used in `url_for`
             r.method(Method::GET).f(|_| httpcodes::HTTPOk);
        })
        .finish();
}
```

How can I add to generated URL a query string like `?name=Alex`? Is there a nice built in way to do it using `HttpRequest.url_for()` (not just append like `url += query_str`)

Answer (score 2):

`url_for` gives you a `Result<Url, UrlGenerationError>`, which you can unwrap and add query parameters using `.set_query`.

```
let mut myurl = req.url_for("foo", &["1", "2", "3"]).unwrap();
myurl.set_query(Some("q=asdf"));
```